# Entity Framework Core cascade delete one to many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

```
public class Station : IEntitie
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<RegulatorySchedule> RegulatoryScheduleDispatchStations { get; set; }    

    public virtual ICollection<RegulatorySchedule> RegulatoryScheduleDestinationStations { get; set; }   
}

public class RegulatorySchedule : IEntitie
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Station DispatchStation { get; set; }      

    public virtual Station DestinationStation { get; set; }     
}


protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
        modelBuilder.Entity<RegulatorySchedule>()
            .HasOne(s => s.DestinationStation)
            .WithMany(s => s.RegulatoryScheduleDestinationStations)
            .OnDelete(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        modelBuilder.Entity<RegulatorySchedule>()
            .HasOne(s => s.DispatchStation)
            .WithMany(s => s.RegulatoryScheduleDispatchStations)
            .OnDelete(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
}
```

The database is created during migration only when I clearly expose the behavior when deleting `Restrict
OnDelete (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.DeleteBehavior.Restrict)`.
Otherwise, it throws an exception:

> "Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   'FK_RegulatorySchedules_Stations_DispatchStationId' on table
>   'RegulatorySchedules' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths.
>     Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other
>   FOREIGN KEY constraints."

I need the removal of the Station Stations of the table and the table-related properties RegulatorySchedules DispatchStation and DestinationStation exposed to NULL.
But Restrict option there is an exception when you delete a SetNull I can not put.
Tell me how to be?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Described "problem" is not related to Entity Framework - this is restriction of MS SQL Server itself. Table with several FKs may have only one of them with *cascade* delete.

So, as soon as you need both FKs to have **cascade** - you should implement such "cleanup" in your code. Set one (or both) FKs to `DeleteBehavior.Restrict`, and in your controller/service prior to removing `Station` manually find and delete all related `RegulatorySchedule`

Comment: Thanks for the add-on migration took place but update-database has caused the error (SQL server error).
In general it is clear about the manual removal related objects, and whether there is SQL server with a different behavior?

Comment: +1, was working fine in my test with SQLite (or at least seemed to be...). I may have forgotten the correct terminology, but I can create a table with 2 FKs that are cascade delete without issue so long as they point to a different table (and don't otherwise form a cycle etc.); it seems to be that it can't cope with having 2 cascade delete FKs to the _same_ table.

Comment: But why would that be valid in EF and a problem in EF-Core if it's relate to SQL server itself? so do MS had problem for many years in EF modeling or is it a new problem exposed via EF-Core modeling? something is not right.

Comment: @VisualMelon, 2 FKs work in your SQLite because SQLite is not MS SQL Server :)

Comment: @G.Y Why you this that this problem does exist in EF ?

Comment: @Dmitry because when I use model-first - creating edmx, EF create sql script that allows the creation of tables when I run it, but in EF-Core, creating same model using extension "entity framework visual editor" which generate the code for  EF-core, upon EnsureCreated I get the OP error too, this had no problem in the classic EF. both targets the same SQL server..

Comment: @G.Y can you compare generated SQL? Either one of EFs ignores ("auto-corrects") one of relation integrity rules (does not set it to delete-cascade) and you have no two delete-cascade in database created, or it does not understand some of your syntax (and again, you have no two delete-cascade)

Comment: @Dmitry no need :) from the direction in your comment we already agree/know either EF generates a problematic SQL or EF-core generates a problematic SQL in regards to this issue - this is what I meant in my first comment, it's not SQL server problem - it is either EF or EF-core problem, one of them is doing something wrong by either allowing the cascaded relations to exist in EF or not allowing them to exist in EF-Core. From your answer regarding SQL I understand it is probably classic EF that is the violator..

Answer (score 10):

Dmitry's answer worked perfectly. For any future traveler a working sample of a mapping table down below.

The code is located in the `OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)` method in your 
`DbContext` class:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AB>()
            .HasKey(e => new { e.AId, e.BId});

modelBuilder.Entity<AB>()
            .HasOne(e => e.A)
            .WithMany(e => e.ABs)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.AId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade); // <= This entity has cascading behaviour on deletion

modelBuilder.Entity<AB>()
            .HasOne(e => e.B)
            .WithMany(e => e.ABs)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.BId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict); // <= This entity has restricted behaviour on deletion
```