# FOREIGN KEY constraint may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. ef core 3 (cannot create a DB at all)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am getting the multiple cascade path error.

My models are 0..1 to 0..1
Or at least that is what i am trying to achieve.

My models look like this:

```
public class House
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }

   [ForeignKey("User")]
   public User Tenant { get; set; }

public class User
{
    public House Home { get; set; }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
```

I have also this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<House>()
        .HasOne(p => p.Tenant)
        .WithOne(t => t.Home)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
}
```

The error is not that i get an error when i delete a object, it simply will not create the DB at all.

I have already been told that this has been solved here:

[Entity Framework Core cascade delete one to many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41711772/entity-framework-core-cascade-delete-one-to-many-relationship)

However i am afraid to say that it does not appear to really address my issue, or if it does i do not understand how it solves it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

//update

Just to clarify. There are many users/tenants and many houses/homes. 
Each of the tenants can have a house but does not always. 
Each of the homes can have a tenant but does not always have one.

Comment: Can you add the table's schema?

Comment: It seems a little bit strange... why are you using ".WithOne(t=> t.Home)" ? Home is an instance of House isn't it ? So it looks like you're doing kind of a circular reference.

Comment: @David. i admit i am probably not using this correctly. I originally did not have the OnModelCreating at all. but was getting the cascade error. so after looking at somewhat similar problems other had, i concluded i needed to add the on delete behavior. So that the records could be set to null when either the house or the tenant is deleted.

Comment: There should be something else (not shown here) which is causing the issue. Or the generated migration is stale. Put the 2 classes in question + fluent configuration *exactly* as shown in a clean new console project and generate migration - there should not be a cascading delete constraint.

Comment: If possible (I assume you're building your db scheme) I would use a more standard EF systaxe : Every PK in each entity should be named "Id" and then when you want to refer to a "parent table" (for example : House entity has a "User" as a Tenant you just need to name it (inside the House entity) as "UserId". EF will automaticaly understand that UserId refers to the column Id of the User entity. This can be done without any OnModelCreating syntax. Start simple !

Comment: When you refer to House from the User entity you'll need to explain EF that this House is not forcely required. This should be done via your OnModelCreating method when configuring the User entity : p.Property(c => c.Home).IsRequired(false);

Comment: @David i am not really sure how i would use this. I tried inserting this code into my onmodelcreating method: modelBuilder.Entity<House>().Property(b => b.Tenant).IsRequired(false); but that just returns a whole bunch if errors

Comment: @David to make it more readable and simpler. i changed the models to be using more standard EF syntax as you recommended above. Still getting the same error though.

Comment: Please read my previous comment. The issue is *not* reproducible with the provided code. So either provide a repro, or when doing so you may find yourself the issue in your real code.

Comment: @IvanStoev i have not created a new simple project as per your advice and it does indeed work, you are correct there is nothing wrong with the original code. I need to find what it is the that additional structure is doing to cause this error. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that Ivan was correct in one of his comments above. The issue was not actually in the code itself. In fact even simpler code will work in this case.
The error was caused by the migrations. I had to remove all migrations and start from scratch. Clearly some of the older model designs clashed with this new addition in a way that it was simply not possible to move forward. The databases had to be recreated from scratch.

Thank you everyone for your help. Especially Ivan and David.

Here are the simple models that do what i needed to do:

```
public class Home
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid? TenantId { get; set; } 
    public Tenant Tenant { get; set; } 
}

public class Tenant
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Home Home { get; set; } 
}
```

I do not even have to override the OnModelCreating.

Answer (score 1):

**Try a very simple thing just to be sure when you start getting errors :**

```
public class User{
   public Guid Id{get; set;}
   public string UserName{ get; set;}
}


public class House{
      public Guid Id {get; set;}
      public string StreetName {get; set;}
      public UserId {get; set;} //this should generate a foreign key to the User table
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<House>().Property(c => c.UserId).IsRequired(false);
}
```

**This should work to create houses that doesn't necessarely requires Users to exist.**

Comment: This simple version does indeed work, i had this before but needed to refer to the house from the user model also. At which point it stopped working. I am now making a new simpler test project to confirm if the code works if it is not inside a more complex structure, as per Ivan's advice

Comment: So you should evolve to a new model and use a UserHome table that will create the link between the user and the home entity. This should work.

Answer (score 0):

So 1 house can have only 1 tenant. And 1 user can stay in only 1 home. Your relationship is 1 to 1. In this case, you can put foreign key in either table, but only 1 table. Then, you don't have issue of cycle cascade.

I suggest to put HouseId in User class, so that you can extend your app to allow 1 house to have many tenants easily later.

Comment: That's not how I read this relationship. Each house has one tennant, and each user has 1 home. If I have 1 home, but rent another, both houses could list me as tennant, but only one of them would be my home. The way I read it, it doesn't say/mean that the user home has to be the "1" house that lists the user as a tennant, so in fact multiple houses can list the same user as a tennant, but only one house can be set as the users home. Or did I miss something?

Comment: I think tenant mean someone who rent the house, not own the house. And also, he mentioned that 1..0 and 1..0 relationship.

Comment: Sorry for not being very clear. There are many users and many houses. 
A user can have a house, but does not always have one. Also a House can have a user (tenant) but does not always have one.

Comment: @Alex-TinLe do you mean not have the object home at all in the user model ? just the houseid?

Answer (score 0):

Here, one foreign key is declared :

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<House>()
        .HasOne(p => p.Tenant)
        .WithOne(t => t.Home)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
}
```

`House.Tenant` is linked to `User.Home`.
The tenant is the resident. Not what you want.

You need declare two foreign key distinct :

Fluent syntax

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasOne(u => u.Home).WithOne();
    modelBuilder.Entity<House>().HasOne(h => h.Tenant).WithOne();
}
```

Attribute syntax

```
public class House
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TenantId")]
    public User Tenant { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    [ForeignKey("HomeId")]
    public House Home { get; set; }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it gives me exactly the same error.