# EF Core - Foreign Key causes cycles or multiple cascade paths while having many to many relationships

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I am trying to create an author entity which has a relationship to a country entity (country of origin of the author) and relationship to a set of countries which are visited by the author. The following is my code

```
public class Author
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int CountryOfOriginId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CountryOfOriginId")]
    public Country CountryOfOrigin { get; set; }

    public ICollection<AuthorCountry> VisitedCountries { get; set; }
}

public class Country
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class AuthorCountry
{
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AuthorId")]
    public Author Author { get; set; }

    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CountryId")]
    public Country Country { get; set; }
}
```

`AuthorCountry` exist to keep the M:N relationship and has the composite key defined as below

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AuthorCountry>()
    .HasKey(c => new
    {
        c.CountryId,
        c.AuthorId
    });
```

I am able to add the migration, however when I try to update the database I am getting the following error:

```
Failed executing DbCommand (23ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
CREATE TABLE [AuthorCountry] (
    [AuthorId] int NOT NULL,
    [CountryId] int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_AuthorCountry] PRIMARY KEY ([CountryId], [AuthorId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_AuthorCountry_Author_AuthorId] FOREIGN KEY ([AuthorId]) REFERENCES [Author] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_AuthorCountry_Countries_CountryId] FOREIGN KEY ([CountryId]) REFERENCES [Countries] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): 
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_AuthorCountry_Countries_CountryId' on table 'AuthorCountry' 
may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. 
Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
```

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41711772/entity-framework-core-cascade-delete-one-to-many-relationship) in which someone reports the similar behaviour, however my case is different that in the `Author` entity I need to have a single `Country` relationship to keep the `CountryOfOrigin` and also need to keep the M:N relationship to keep the list of visited countries.

How can I solve the problem?

**Fix: (thanks for the hint @lrpe)**

I edited the `AuthorCountry` as below (removed the ForiegnKey attribute)

```
public class AuthorCountry
{
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    //[ForeignKey("AuthorId")] : Handled by Fluent API - to override default delete behaviour
    public Author Author { get; set; }

    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CountryId")]
    public Country Country { get; set; }
}
```

Finally added the below fluent api config to over-ride the default cascading delete behaviour

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AuthorCountry>()
    .HasOne(a => a.Country)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(a => a.CountryId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You receive this error message because in SQL Server, a table cannot appear more than one time in a list of all the cascading referential actions that are started by either a `DELETE` or an `UPDATE` statement. The tree of cascading referential actions must only have one path to a particular table on the cascading referential actions tree.

([Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-1785-database-engine-error?view=sql-server-ver15))

I'm assuming that `CountryOfOrigin` is also a cascading relationship.

Suppose that you delete a `Country`. The deletion will cascade to `Author` and `AuthorCountry`, and will cascade again from `Author` to `AuthorCountry`. There are thus two paths to `AuthorCountry` from the one `DELETE` statement, which is forbidden.

To fix the problem, one of your foreign keys must be changed to a non-cascading referential action.

Besides, does it really make sense for countries to be deletable if they are referenced by other records? Unless the purpose of the `Country` table is something other than containing a permanent list of countries that exist in the world, I would suggest making foreign keys that reference this table non-cascading.